I'm facing the error[E0432]: unresolved import ; no external crate, but I'm following exact instructions
I'm trying to recreate a Turing Machine Simulator using WASM + React just for fun and to learn a bit about WebAssembly and front-end. As I wasn't very interested in the actual TM details, I decided to use this code created by Philipp Engelmann, but I'm facing a problem related to importing modules in Rust, I'm fairly new to Rust, but in my past projects I had no problem with it.
This is how my project files look like:
|-- turing-wasm/
|   |-- pkg
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- direction.rs
|   |   |-- state.rs
|   |   |-- tape.rs
|   |   |-- transition.rs
|   |   |-- turing.rs
|   |   |-- lib.rs
    `-- target

lib.rs is where I'll handle the WASM part, and has the following:
mod state;
mod tape;
mod direction;
mod transition;
mod turing;

I get exactly four [E0432] errors when running cargo build, all in turing.rs
use tape;
use direction;
use transition;
use state;

It says (I just copied the error for tape, but it says exactly the same thing for all 'uses':
error[E0432]: unresolved import `tape`
  --> src\turing.rs:23:5
   |
23 | use tape;
   |     ^^^^ no external crate `tape`

But honestly, I don't know if I'm being stupid or what, as I've said, I'm still new to Rust. I'm trying to follow the code provided by the website, but still, this error happened out of nowhere, does anyone know how to approach this?

This is not how you import from other files in Rust. I checked their repo just in case it was a typo or other miscommunication with the blog, but no, its just like that. See How do I import from a sibling module? for how to do that properly (in your case adding a crate:: prefix is likely all you need, i.e. use crate::tape; for instance). I pray you don't continue following the blog since its not clear what else might be wrong about it.

There is no mod tape; nor a crate named tape available in turing.rs, that's what use tape; is looking for. You want to use an absolute path if you're referring to things in the crate root (lib.rs).

@kmdreko note that the repo (and blog) used Rust edition 2015, in which importing sibling modules that way was valid.

@Jmb nooo, I even thought about that but somehow thought it worked differently then. how embarrassing :(
